# Как вычислить значение в пересечении каждого столбца и строки в СКД 1С?

Tags: 1с

В настройке отчета в СКД добавил справочники с пользователями и группами доступа. В макете сделал шаблон как на скриншоте. В 1 столбце выводятся все профили базы данных. В строке с пользователем выводятся все пользователи. Ограничение тут лишнее, пока не нужно.

[image]

Как на пересечении пользователя и профиля написать значение Истина, если у данного пользователя есть профиль?

Сама функция проверки у меня есть, но как подставить ее вычисление в каждую ячейку?

```
Функция ПользовательИмеетПрофиль(ИмяПользователя, НаименованиеПрофиля)  
    
    Запрос = Новый Запрос;  
    Запрос.Текст = "ВЫБРАТЬ
                   |  ГруппыДоступа.Ссылка
                   |ИЗ
                   |  Справочник.ГруппыДоступа КАК ГруппыДоступа
                   |ГДЕ
                   |  ГруппыДоступа.Пользователь.Наименование = &Пользователь
                   |И 
                   |  ГруппыДоступа.Наименование = &Профиль"; 
    
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Пользователь", ИмяПользователя);
    Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Профиль", НаименованиеПрофиля);
    Выборка = Запрос.Выполнить().Выгрузить().ВыгрузитьКолонку(0);
  
    Возврат Выборка.Количество() > 0;

КонецФункции
```

Answer (score 0):

СКД позволяет обращаться к функциям общих модулей - [Использование функций общих модулей СКД](https://its.1c.ru/db/metod8dev/content/3332/hdoc)